# Why does this CSS line comment out all the other code in eclipse?

Tags: html, eclipse

So I am running the latest and greatest eclipse and it seems this line of code always comments out everything underneath it. I don't think this code is wrong? This line was included in the foundation css framework download and this is what I usually use?

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Big thanks in advance!

Edit** I am pretty sure its supposed to be this, is this correct?

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
```

[image]

Comment: You may have a mismatched pair of `>` in your `endif`. Try closing the `<` and see how that works.

Comment: I didn't write this code it was downloaded from http://foundation.zurb.com/ but ill check

Comment: Whatever the problem is, your Edit** version isn't what you want, following the same format as the conditional comments preceding it would cause IE 9+ and anything non-IE to not have an opening html tag.

Comment: So what do I put there and why is eclipse saying its bad? Dreamweaver or any other program doesnt.

Comment: That's a good question, and I have no idea. I don't use eclipse, so I can't help you there; those conditional comments are standard boilerplate, so it's weird that eclipse would have a problem with it.

Comment: I can't tell because the entire line is highlighted in your screen shot, but is the html tag itself on that line showing as a comment?

Comment: yes the whole document is

Comment: That's not a CSS comment. That's an HTML comment. In fact, this has nothing to do with CSS/HTML5/CSS3 whatsoever.

Comment: ok... but my question was why is it commenting out the rest of the code in eclipse?

Comment: If all browsers appear to handle this correctly, then it's probably a bug in Eclipse.

Comment: What happens when you use your second alternative...

Comment: It does not comment everything out